# ”It will very enjoy” is this correct?

Tags: grammar

Grammatically they said ”It will very enjoy” is correct but A friend said it's kinda strange. ”It will be enjoying” maybe a good grammar?

Comment: I think you want *it will be very enjoyable*, but you don't give any context so it is hard to say.

Comment: ... who said that it is grammatically correct?

Comment: Hi, Javalatte. I just checked in the grammar application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a sentence with a be-verb, the be-verb has to be followed by a noun or an adjective:

> It is a tree - *noun*
>   It is good - *adjective*

If you look at **enjoy** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enjoy), you will see that it can be a verb, but it cannot be a noun or an adjective. Your sentence is therefore grammatically incorrect.

For many verbs, you can make them into an adjective by adding **-able**. You can check whether this is possible for a particular verb by checking in a dictionary. The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enjoyable) does list **enjoyable** as an adjective, so it is grammatically correct to say

> It will be very enjoyable

Comment: This isn't true. *It is dripping.* That's a present-participle verb. Or *it is slowly dripping.* That's an adverb and a verb.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @JasonBassford a participle is an adjectival form of a verb, in the same way as gerunds and infinitives are noun forms of verbs. https://www.englishgrammar.org/adjective-or-participle/